# Clarification on an excerpt involving number of functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Here is an excerpt from a book I am reading:

> Consider an agent that has to recognize letters of the alphabet.
>   Suppose the agent observes a binary image, a $30×30$ grid of pixels, where each
>   of the $900$ grid points is either on or off (i.e., it is not using any color or gray scale
>   information). The action is to determine which of the letters {a, . . . , z} is drawn
>   in the image. There are $2^{900}$ different states of the image, and so $26^{2^{900}}$  different functions from the image state into the characters {a, . . . , z}. We cannot even
>   represent such functions in terms of the state space. Instead, we define features
>   of the image, such as line segments, and define the function from images to
>   characters in terms of these features.

Can someone explain why there are $26^{2^{900}}$ different functions from the image state to the characters? If we treat the set of image states as the domain, and the set of characters as the codomain, then each image state could map to one of $26$ possible characters. So at most we would have $2^{900} * 26$ *possible* functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assign a letter of the alphabet to each image state, we're making a $26$-way choice $2^{900}$ times; this can be done in

$$\underbrace{26\cdot 26\cdot\ldots\cdot 26}_{2^{900}\text{ copies}}=26^{2^{900}}$$

different ways. Each of those ways is one of the functions in question.

Comment: Suppose we added a new character 'null' which is reserved for image states that do not represent any alphabetical character. Would the number of possible functions then be $27^{2^{900}}$?

Comment: @Vizuna: Yes, it would.